# Momentjs not been displayed in package.json file on meteor

Tags: reactjs, meteor, momentjs

The momentjs package for me is been displayed in my packages file but not my package.json file, will this cause problems.

I used the following command to install it.

```
meteor add momentjs:moment​
```

Should I install through npm and add --save

[image: package.json]
[image: packages]

Comment: Try `npm install moment --save`

Comment: This worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Meteor add` is for adding meteor packages which you can find on Atmosphere

To install NPM packages you need to use `meteor install moment --save`